# Inserting data to Related Models when tables are dynamic

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to create a function which collects data from any form in the system and saves it to the appropriate table.

For example:

Case One: Form for student registration involves two Model

1) student_master
2) student_departments

Case Two: Form for student payment fee involves two Model

1) student_master
2) student_payments

What I a trying to achieve is that have a central place for saving instead of re-writing the same method for each form with just different model names.

My current progress is that saving of data in each particular form's model is achieved but that thing is that I am not able to save the foreign key value

for example:

`student_master => [ id=>1, name => 'John Doe'....]`

`student_payments => [id=>1, department => 'Science'], [id => 2, deparment => 'Math']`

This is the current array which gets formed and based on this I insert in the model but `studentmaster_id` in the student_payments table is missing and it saves as 0

```
/*
 * function to insert data into the particular table
 * after getting the namespaces of each table from the helper functions
 */
public function insertFormData()
{

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->tableNames); $i++) {
        // get the namespace of the table name
        $model = CustomHelper::getNameSpace($this->tableNames[$i]);
        // $model => /var/www/html/erp/app/Models/sales/StudentMaster
        $model::insert($this->tableCollections[$this->tableNames[$i]]);

    }

}
```

I need to find a way to store the foreign key without hardcoding any of the table/model names.

Comment: I think it would be clearer to separate these out into their own models for the sake of code clarity and contingency. I am not sure how much more efficient having 1 method that is confusing to read is against a small insert method for each model - out of interest, why are you trying to achieve it like this?

Comment: I have already mentioned this in before about why I am trying to achieve this. The thing is there could be multiple forms in future and inserting data into table is the core functionality of the system. I don't want to keep adding logic for different forms and want to centralise place for this. @party-ring